# JTextArea append keeps separating my text

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

So I have this code

```
ticketAmountAdult = (tickets.getSelectedIndex() + 1) * ADULTBASE;
//String joinTogther = list1.getSelectedValue()+"--$" + ticketAmountAdult;
t5.append(list1.getSelectedValue()+"--$" + ticketAmountAdult);
```

But in the textArea it keeps showing up like so

[image: The picture]

I want them to be on the same line then when I call Append again the next text would then be on a separate line

Comment: Does `list1.getSelectedValue()` contain a new line character? Maybe try trimming any white space from it